# After upgrade, every phone call displays an ad?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, ads

Running on an LG Stylus 3 on Android 7.0 security patch date Oct. 1, 2017.

After a recent upgrade every time I make a call, after hanging up I see a notice

"Quickly record a Voice memo"
@   Writen an email

and then an ad.  I don't think this is an app, I think this was done to me by the update.  But if there is any way to get rid of it, I would like to know.

I don't want to be offered a choice to record a voice memo, when I'm done with a call I want back to the main screen.  And I certainly don't want to see an ad.

Is this google or some third party? Is there any way for me to tell who is benefitting/originating from a given ad?

Comment: You can easily check to see if this is a third party app or not. Go into safe mode, and while there, make a call and see if the ad comes in

Comment: A screenshot of the notice and ad might help. Though, I guess there's a 3rd-party app (malware) that monitors the phone state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot I had added recording software.  Going into safemode definitely established that it was not Android itself.  Then the question was how to find the app.   I don't have a great answer, but scanning through all the apps showed me that I had added one, and denying it privileges fixed the problem.

As a side-note, Android desperately needs a way to identify a page or notification and see who is responsible for it.

Answer (score -1):

Try Adblock, or if you have root access you can install xposed installer and module to block ads even more